# Connecting from QGIS to PostGIS database using OGR toolbox?

Tags: postgis, gdal, pyqgis, ogr2ogr, qgis-processing

I am trying to write a script to import/append mutiple layers into an existing PostGIS database. I am trying to use the  GDAL/OGR toolbox algo "Import Vector into PostGIS database (new connection)".

Here's my code:

```
vl  =QgsVectorLayer("D:/Users/Ravi_narayanan/Documents/VDLF/test2.shp","test2","ogr")

processing.runalg('gdalogr:importvectorintopostgisdatabasenewconnection', vl, 3, vl.crs().authid(),vl.crs().authid(),vl.crs().authid(), "172.22.140.42", "5432", "ivy01", "YVI", "ivy01!", "TEST1", "new", "ID","ID", "geom", 0,"","","0,1,0,1",False,"","20000",False, True, False, False, True, False,False,False,"")
```

This gives me the following error:

GDAL execution console output
            FAILURE:

```
        Unable to open datasource `port=5432' with the following drivers.
```

The list of drivers contains PostgreSQL. 
The connection to the database works fine using a standard PyQGIS uri object.

When i tried using the toolbox GUI. The GDAL/OGR console command is as follws:

```
ogr2ogr.exe -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PostgreSQL PG:" "host=172.22.149.42 port=5432 dbname=YVI password=ivy01! active_schema=TEST1 user=ivy01" " -lco DIM=2 D:\Users\Ravi_narayanan\Documents\VDLF\test4.shp test4 -overwrite -nlt POINT -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco FID=id -nln new -spat 480030.5 6691467.0 484106.5 6696344.0 -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI
```

There is a `" "`after `PostgreSQL PG:` instead of a `"` when compared with the GUI of Import with available connections.

i'm using QGIS 2.14.11 and the number of parameters is not the same as in the link JGH gave.

```
ALGORITHM: Import Vector into PostGIS database (new connection)
INPUT_LAYER <ParameterVector>
GTYPE <ParameterSelection>
A_SRS <ParameterCrs>
T_SRS <ParameterCrs>
S_SRS <ParameterCrs>
HOST <ParameterString>
PORT <ParameterString>
USER <ParameterString>
DBNAME <ParameterString>
PASSWORD <ParameterString>
SCHEMA <ParameterString>
TABLE <ParameterString>
PK <ParameterString>
PRIMARY_KEY <parameters from INPUT_LAYER>
GEOCOLUMN <ParameterString>
DIM <ParameterSelection>
SIMPLIFY <ParameterString>
SEGMENTIZE <ParameterString>
SPAT <ParameterExtent>
CLIP <ParameterBoolean>
WHERE <ParameterString>
GT <ParameterString>
OVERWRITE <ParameterBoolean>
APPEND <ParameterBoolean>
ADDFIELDS <ParameterBoolean>
LAUNDER <ParameterBoolean>
INDEX <ParameterBoolean>
SKIPFAILURES <ParameterBoolean>
PROMOTETOMULTI <ParameterBoolean>
PRECISION <ParameterBoolean>
OPTIONS <ParameterString
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in

> processing.runalg('gdalogr:importvectorintopostgisdatabasenewconnection',
>   vl, 3, **vl.crs().authid()**,**vl.crs().authid()**,**vl.crs().authid()**,
>   "172.22.140.42", "5432" ...

because the CRS is written 3 times, while the algorithm expects only 2 (source + target). If all other params are OK, it should work by removing the extra CRS.

You can check the parameters [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/ogr_miscellaneous.html#id10)

Comment: It throws the same error when give an empty string